# Using a interface type to instantiate a class object that implements the interface

Tags: java

Some confusion with using a interface as a type to instantiate a class object. Why do we need the interface as a type? When we can use the class instead? As the class implements the interface anyway. I know you cannot instantiate an interface.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

```
   public interface SortRecords {
        int query(int rowId);
    }

    public class OurPrice implements SortRecords {
        @Override
        public int query(int rowId) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void test() {
        /* 
         * Why has the interface as the type? 
         */
        SortRecords sorterV1 = new OurPrice();
        sorterV1.query(1);

        /* 
         * Why not just do like this? 
         */
        OurPrice sorterV2 = new OurPrice();
        sorterV2.query(2);
    }
```

Comment: what if there exists another ``class`` implementing ``SortRecords ``, e.g.: ``public class TheirPrice implements SortRecords { ... }``?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interface declares the *contract*, and provides you with the freedom to specify any other class providing the same contract. So the code referencing the interface is agnostic to the *implementation* you're providing.

In the above example, it's not particularly useful. However, in a wider context, a factory could provide you with any implementation it likes (even varying during runtime). As a consumer, you don't have to worry. You simply communicate using the interface and the contract (methods) it provides.

Answer (score 1):

basics of polymorphism.

read here http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/PolymorphismInterfaces1.html

Comment: Please consider adding relevant parts of the linked source to your answer as links can die and become useless to other users.